# how do i carry on values from one ViewController to another, which are user input and 'calculated'

Tags: ios, xcode, global-variables, extern

I want to carry out the 'TotalLabel' Calculation, onto another ViewContoller known as 'AdultPayNowViewController'. I also want to carry out the 'x' value, which is a UITextField that the user inputs a quantity onto  'AdultPayNowViewController'

//AdultTicketCalculator.h

```
@interface StudentTicketCalculatorViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *Quantity;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Pricelabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *TotalLabel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *CheckoutButton;

}

-(IBAction)calculate;
-(IBAction)clear;

@end

\\AdultTicketCalculator.m

-(IBAction)calculate {

    float x = ([Quantity.text floatValue]);
    float c = x*15;

    TotalLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", c];

}

-(IBAction)clear {

    Quantity.text =@"";
    Pricelabel.text =@"$15.00";
    TotalLabel.text =@"";
```

Comment: I still say check out the singleton method.  You send whatever variable you want into the singleton, And can call it from anywhere in your app.

Comment: N.B. you could also use the class method `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", c];` instead.

Comment: The answer depends on how you're getting to this other controller. You should provide more information about how this controller and the other one are situated in the app. Does one create the other? Are you segueing to this other controller? etc.

Comment: @rdlemar look at the edit, is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

First off, these values probably shouldn't even live in a controller. If they're really values, they ought to be a part of a model that is shared by or passed between controllers in the usual MVC manner.

But moving on, there are really only a few ways to pass values between controllers (or any object, for that matter). Most straight forward is, you create a custom initializer in `AdultPayNowViewController` called `-initWithTotalLabel:andXValue:` and created that controller within `StudentTicketCalculatorViewController` like so:

```
[[AdultPayNowViewController alloc] initWithTotalLabel:totalLabel andXValue:x];
```

Or from some shared parent like:

```
[[AdultPayNowViewController alloc] initWithTotalLabel:[studentController totalLabel] andXValue:[studientController x]];
```

Likewise, if you don't need those values for the adult controller's initialization, you could always make them properties and set them directly:

```
adultController = [[AdultPayNowViewController alloc] init];
[adultController setTotalLabel:[childController TotalLabel]];
[adiltController setXValue:[childController x]];
```

Another possibility would be to make the student controller a delegate of the adult controller, and make the adult controller ask its delegate for the values of `totalLabel` and `x` when it needs them.

Finally, you could pass student controller as a parameter or user data to a method or notification responsible for creating adult controller, and then use its properties to either set or initialize adult controller with the desired values. This is more or less the approved "Storyboard" way of doing things, I believe, with everything going down in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`.